# My faucet leaks when I turn it off but stops when I move the handle to the on position just a tad

Tags: faucet, leaking

I’ve replaced the seat and spring hoping the dripping would stop. But now when I turn the handle off it drips. I can move the handle toward the on position just a fraction and it stops leaking. What would cause this to happen? I have a two handle Delta kitchen faucet

Comment: "the handle" vs. "two handle"? Which is it, 1 or 2? If it is 2, which one (hot or cold or both) has the problem?

Comment: can we see the beast

Comment: "can we see the beast" means please upload a picture of the faucet